# Azure Datafactory Web Activity

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-api-management

I have developed an Function app and published the same via Azure APIM. I am trying to call the API(APIM) from Data factory Web Activity, which fails with the below. However when I use the Azure function URL + Function key directly in WebActivity this works fine.

So I want to be able to call a REST endpoint internal to my organization from Azure Data Factory using Web Activity. Appreciate any directions on this.

```
{
    "errorCode": "2108",
    "message": "Error calling the endpoint. Response status code: ",
    "failureType": "UserError
}
```

Comment: One thing to check is if your API in APIM is added to an open product, and if not to make sure that you're passing correct subscription key in call to APIM.

Comment: There is a generic REST connector now. Have you tried using it instead of the web activity? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest
There is also now an Azure Function activity where you can directly run an Azure function as a step.

Comment: @VitaliyKurokhtin Yep the API is added to a Product and as long as I pass in the correct subscription key this should hold good. To add to that yes am passing in the right subscription key if not the call will fail with 491 Unauthorized access. Here is the issue is am not able to reach the API endpoint.

Comment: Did you try calling APIM outside of Data Factory? Does it work?

Comment: Yes it does work perfectly. The only problem I see could be that my APIM service is on an internal vnet and since ADF running on the public IP is not able to reach the endpoint. I could whitelist the ADF ip's but I think that's not a good solution.

Comment: @mmarie Haven't tried the REST connector, let me look into it. Also the requirement is this generic API will be used across multiple services and applications, so using Azure Functions is not an option.

Comment: Ah, so it's in an internal VNET. Well, it's by design not accessible from outside. Your options are: put Azure data Factory into the same VNET (if possible), whitelist, or use App Gateway (or something similar) to open a public endpoint in a VNET, or use external VNET.